# Best practice for writing to hadoop from spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, partition

I was reviewing some code written by a co-worker, and I found a method like this:

```
def writeFile(df: DataFrame,
              partitionCols: List[String],
              writePath: String): Unit {

    val df2 = df.repartition(partitionCols.get.map(col): _*)
    val dfWriter = df2.write.partitionBy(partitionCols.get.map(col): _*)
    dfWriter
        .format("parquet")
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .option("compression", "snappy")
        .save(writePath)

}
```

Is it generally good practice to call `repartition` on a predefined set of columns like this, and then call `partitionBy`, and then save to disk?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you call `repartition` with the same columns as the `partitionBy` to have a single parquet file in each partition. This is being achieved here. Now you could argue that this could mean the parquet file size becoming large or worse could cause memory  overflow.

This problem generally handled by adding a row_number to the Dataframe and then specify the number of documents than each parquet file can have. Something like

```
val repartitionExpression =colNames.map(col) :+ floor(col(RowNumber) / docsPerPartition)
// now use this to repartition
```

To answer the next part as `persist after partitionBy` that is not needed here as after partition it is directly written to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

To help you understand the differences between `partitionBy()` and `repartition()`, repartition on the dataframe uses a Hash based partitioner which takes COL as well as NumOfPartitions basing on which generates a hash value and buckets the data.

By default `repartition()` creates 200 partitions. Because of possibility of collisions there is good chance of partitioning multiple records with different keys into same buckets.

On the other hand the `partitionBy()` takes COL by which the partitions are purely based on the unique keys. The partitions are proportional to the no: of unique keys in the data.

In repartition case there is a good chance of writing empty files. But, in the case of partitionBy there will not be any empty files.

Comment: My `repartition` call also takes column names, so it probably doesn't use a RangePartitioner. Perhaps it does by default, but that's not what is happening in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Is your job CPU-bound, memory-bound, network-IO bound, or disk-IO bound?

First 2 cases are significant if df2 is sufficiently large, and other answers correctly address those cases.

If your job is disk-IO bound (and you see yourself writing large files to HDFS frequently in future), many cloud providers will let you pick a faster SSD disk for an extra charge.

Also [Sandy Ryza](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/) recommends keeping --executor-cores under 5:

> I’ve noticed that the HDFS client has trouble with tons of concurrent threads. A rough guess is that at most five tasks per executor can achieve full write throughput, so it’s good to keep the number of cores per executor below that number.